# Display Wordpress posts from left to right in two columns

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display my Wordpress posts across two columns. At the moment, they run down one column. I'm also getting the categories repeating in the col-lg-2 div as I scroll down. Any tips? Thanks!

```
    <div class="container">
    <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ https://m0n.co/l
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=-1' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <?php the_category(', '); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: what exactly output you want? can you please add image or else?

Comment: I've got about thirty posts where I want the featured image and the post title displayed for each post. I want the posts to run left to right instead of running down one column. @Dixit